# Почему не переходит на другие страницы?

Tags: php, laravel

При переходе на любую другую страницу, вываливается ошибка: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Роуты:

```
Route::get('/about', function(){
    return view('about');
});

Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index');
```

В файле welcome.blade.php - главная страница

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
    Napotest
</div>

<div class="links">
    <a href="{{ url('/about') }}">О нас</a>
    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Войти или зарегистрироваться</a>
    <a href="{{ url('/posts') }}">Список статей</a>
    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Список пользователей</a>
</div>
```

PostController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = $this->model->all();
    return view('post.all', compact('posts'));
}
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Настройки виртуального хоста

```
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>
```

Роуты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Физически эти две страницы существуют about.blade.php и all.blade.php. Почему всегда появляется ошибка??

Интересно, если в строке браузера написать: http://localhost/Projects/mysite/public/index.php/about - страница открывается!

Comment: покажите настройки .htaccess

Comment: @AntonKucenko, добавил к вопросу

Comment: А вы уверены что у вас Апач, а не nginx? Если нет, то .htaccess не используется.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, запущен запущена сборка xampp с апачем..

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код для настройки виртуального хоста, пожалуйста.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, добавил к вопросу

Answer (score 2):

Попробуте сделать так: 
В роутах

```
Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index')->name('posts') //именной роут
```

В welcome.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('posts') }}">Список статей</a> //вписывается имя именного роута
```

А в вашем случае возможно ошибка в том, что берется не относительный путь, а полный, но я не уверен

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но, к сожалению, я уже так пробовал - результат тот же. А как проверить какие пути? Или где это можно поправить?

Comment: Ещё вариант сделать так (в этом способе можно использовать laravel константы типо url()->full, чтобы не полностью весь путь):

<a href="{{ url('http://localhost/Projects/mysite/public/index.php/about ') }}">О нас</a>

<a href="{{ url('url()->full.'/about ') }}">О нас</a>
Или же 
 <a href="{{ url('./about ') }}">О нас</a>
Но это врятли

Comment: Все также. По каким-то причинам не видит вьюшки

Comment: Можно проверить ещё правильность директорий, а вообще урла очень странная, странно что  из index.php открывается файл, а ещё более странно, что index.php вообще показывается, я думал что laravel на роутинге это скрывает

Comment: index.php не показывается, просто можно явно указать, и посмотреть заходит вообще или нет

Comment: У вас настройки сервера не корректны. Сначала проверьте роуты: php artisan route:list

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, добавил скин роутов к вопросу. А в чем некорректность?

Answer (score 0):

вот где вы ошиблись:
вы в папке **wiew/post/all.blade.php** (создайте здесь файл и увидите результат)

чтобы получить фалй из папки: **view/all.blade.php**  вам нужно в конроллере указать

```
return view('all', compact('posts'));
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложенный ответ, но у меня `all.blade.php` лежит в `views/post`

Comment: или ещё проще: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

Всем большое спасибо за ответы! Я изменил файл .htaccess на то, что ниже и все заработало!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```